# component is being duplicated in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

component is getting duplicate on screen on each useState change even if i add depencancy in useEffect

how can we avoid mounting and how cac we update existing component

here im facing the issue

im using a external library in react application

I'm using `yasgui` library for sparql query editor in react application
this is the code im using for updating the yasqui(yasr) response result

I'm targeting a element directly by using getElementById

```
 const [result , setResult] = React.useState([])
    React.useEffect(( )=>{
    var yasr = new YASR(document.getElementById("yasr"), {
     getUsedPrefixes: {},
          drawOutputSelector: true,
          drawDownloadIcon: false,
    }
     yasr.setResponse({
          data: result.data,
          contentType: "application/sparql-results+json",
          status: 200,
         executionTime: 1000,
        });
    },[ result ])
```

element

```
<div id ="yasr" ></div>
```

how can we update the yasr results without rendering(duplicate) component while useState change
if i got any help that is so appricatable

thankyou

Comment: you should use refs to point to class instances, and you only need to initiate them on a mounting useEffect hook (i.e. empty dependency array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are trying to use a single `useEffect` hook to create/attach to the element ***and*** update the data, with a dependency on the `result` state. Each time the `result` state updates a new YASR object is created.

Split the logic into two effects: (1) a mounting effect to create the YASR object once and (2) an effect to update the data when the `result` state updates. Use a React ref to store the YASR instance.

Example:

```
const [result , setResult] = React.useState([]);
const yasrRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const yasr = new YASR(
    document.getElementById("yasr"),
    {
      getUsedPrefixes: {},
      drawOutputSelector: true,
      drawDownloadIcon: false,
    },
  );

  yasrRef.current = yasr;
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  yasrRef.current.setResponse({
    data: result.data,
    contentType: "application/sparql-results+json",
    status: 200,
    executionTime: 1000,
  });
}, [result]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want by setting a ref pointing to the YASR class/object.

Then you can use or reference to YASR wherever you want in your code.

In that way you just instantiate YASR once and then you use it whenever you want and it's not dependant on the state changes.

```
const yasrRef = React.useRef()
    React.useEffect(() => {
    // init YASR
    yasrRef.current = new YASR(document.getElementById("yasr"), {
      getUsedPrefixes: {},
      drawOutputSelector: true,
      drawDownloadIcon: false,
}
  }, [])
```